# Vertical align content of table - with using automatic linebreak (tabularx)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, line-breaking

I'm searching for (simple) method to get rid of the unbeatiful white spacing that is creating by using for example this minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken
\usepackage{booktabs} %Professionelle Tabellen
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} %Tabellen mit Legenden
\usepackage{tabularx} %automatische Zeilenumbruch ermöglicht
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Übersicht der prinzipiellen Maschinenteile einer AM}
        \centering
        \label{uebersicht}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{clX}
            \toprule
            Symbol & Bezeichnung  & Erläuterung \\ \midrule
            Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat & Bauplattform mit Hubtisch &   Die Bauplattform beinhaltet die Bauplatte, auf der das Bauteil gefertigt wird und einen Mechanismus zum bewegen der Bauplattform\\
            Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat & Material in Verwendung & Symbolisiert den Platz und die Art des verwendeten Materials \\
            Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat & Strahl-oder Energiequelle & Zeigt welche Energie oder Strahlquelle für den Prozess genutzt wird.  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Picutre]

The first column would be filled with pictures, the second with the title and the third with a description.

How can I get rid of the white space?

**EDIT**
And I would like to have some spacing between the rows :) That would be perfect.

Thank you very much so far.

Your's sincerely,
Tim

P.S. 
I also put it on [golatex](http://golatex.de/tabelle-mit-tabularx-fuer-automatischen-zeilenumbruch-wie-z-t14684.html) - a german community. Sorry

Comment: Crosspost to [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,68934.html#68934)

Comment: `latin1` is rather outdated, isn't it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, why?

Comment: @daleif: I've not seen it for a long time, at least I think I remember this way

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to use it. For example listings does not work fully with utf8 encoding, but work fine with latin1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using m-columns

To change the spacing, you can use the capabilities of package `booktabs`. Better would be to make a more generic change.

[image: timTabularMitte2]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Übersicht der prinzipiellen Maschinenteile einer AM}
    \centering
    \label{uebersicht}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{4cm}>{\raggedright}m{3cm}X}
        \toprule
        Symbol & Bezeichnung  & Erläuterung \\ \midrule
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}& Bauplattform mit Hubtisch &   Die Bauplattform beinhaltet die Bauplatte, auf der das Bauteil gefertigt wird und einen Mechanismus zum bewegen der Bauplattform\\
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}& Material
        in Verwendung & Symbolisiert den Platz und die Art des
        verwendeten Materials \\\addlinespace[3cm]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}&Strahl- oder Energiequelle & Zeigt welche Energie oder
Strahlquelle für den Prozess genutzt wird.  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this the correct way to add some spacing between the rows:

`\def\arraystretch{1.5}%`

Or is there a better way to this?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you said images in first column, you can use `adjustbox` package with `export` option and align the images at the top.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken
\usepackage{booktabs} %Professionelle Tabellen
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} %Tabellen mit Legenden
\usepackage{tabularx} %automatische Zeilenumbruch ermöglicht
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Übersicht der prinzipiellen Maschinenteile einer AM}
        \centering
        \label{uebersicht}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{clX}
            \toprule
            Symbol & Bezeichnung  & Erläuterung \\ \midrule
            \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image-a} & Bauplattform mit Hubtisch &   Die Bauplattform beinhaltet die Bauplatte, auf der das Bauteil gefertigt wird und einen Mechanismus zum bewegen der Bauplattform\\
            \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image-b} & Material in Verwendung & Symbolisiert den Platz und die Art des verwendeten Materials \\[4ex]
            \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image-c} & Strahl-oder Energiequelle & Zeigt welche Energie oder Strahlquelle für den Prozess genutzt wird.  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be set with the `makecell` package. It allows for line breaks in cells and  adding vertical spacing between rows in preamble. Its `\thead` and `\makecell` commands also allow for common formatting of cells. I added the `caption` package to have a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

If adding vertical spacing between rows doesn't work with the `\makegapedcells` command (it has some incompatibilities), you can use the `cellspace`package, which defines minimal vertical spacing between rows (above and below). All you have to do ids prefix the qualifiers of the relevant columns with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken
\usepackage{booktabs} %Professionelle Tabellen
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} %Tabellen mit Legenden
\usepackage{tabularx} %automatische Zeilenumbruch ermöglicht
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{tc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Übersicht der prinzipiellen Maschinenteile einer AM}
    \centering
    \label{uebersicht}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ScSlS{X}}
        \toprule
        \thead{Symbol} & \thead{Bezeichnung} &\thead{Erläuterung} \\ \midrule
        \makecell{Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat} & Bauplattform mit Hubtisch & Die Bauplattform beinhaltet die Bauplatte, auf der das Bauteil gefertigt wird und einen Mechanismus zum bewegen der Bauplattform\\
        \makecell{Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat} & Material in Verwendung & Symbolisiert den Platz und die Art des verwendeten Materials \\
        \makecell{Dies ist Platz\\der über mehrere\\ zeilen geht und\\viel Spaß dabei hat} & Strahl-oder Energiequelle & Zeigt welche Energie oder Strahlquelle für den Prozess genutzt wird. \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do really like, that you cann correct the vertical spacing bewteen the rows. 
But with the /makegapedcells it's sadly crashing the export. 
I get about 50 Erros in the same row with 

`Missing$ inserted. \end{tabularx}` and `Extra {, or forgotten $. \end{tabularx}`

Any idea what I've done wrong?
(there's nothing missing - as long I deactive \makegapedcells it works

Comment: You've done nothing wrong. This command seems to have some incompatibilities with other packages. You can try to use the `cellspace` package instead. See my updated answer and code.

Comment: I think this is a very good solution. I will try again if I get it working. But trying out cellspaceing resulted in the same problem.

The minimal example is working nice.
It seems I'm still doing somethings wrong with your method. But I'm trying thank you :D

Comment: Probably a conflict with a package/command. Try commenting everything else out, then uncomment progressively until you localise the source of the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken
\usepackage{booktabs} %Professionelle Tabellen
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} %Tabellen mit Legenden
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx} %automatische Zeilenumbruch ermöglicht

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Übersicht der prinzipiellen Maschinenteile einer AM}
        \centering
        \label{uebersicht}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{4cm}L{3cm}X}
            \toprule
            Symbol & Bezeichnung  & Erläuterung \\ \midrule
            Dies ist Platz der über mehrere zeilen geht und viel Spaß dabei hat & Bauplattform mit Hubtisch &   Die Bauplattform beinhaltet die Bauplatte, auf der das Bauteil gefertigt wird und einen Mechanismus zum bewegen der Bauplattform\\
            Dies ist Platz der über mehrere zeilen geht und viel Spaß dabei hat & Material in Verwendung & Symbolisiert den Platz und die Art des verwendeten Materials \\
            Dies ist Platz der über mehrere zeilen geht und viel Spaß dabei hat & Strahl-oder Energiequelle & Zeigt welche Energie oder Strahlquelle für den Prozess genutzt wird.  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]